# Exchange json web tokens in request content between browser and server?

Tags: jwt

In the tutorial I am currently using the jwt is send by a header called 'x-access-tokens'. In my case it would be fine, if I can send it in rquest content.

My question is, if I can do this without violating any terms?

Comment: if you add in request context , in your filters/interceptors you have to read it and handle your authorization manually.

Comment: Yes I will do that anyway. I don't see an problem, how the token is transfered, as far it is crypted by https. url, header or request context, should not be the problem. ... ok the url is displayed by the browser in the adressbar, but that is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using cookies so you don't have to define or add any headers it will be sent to your backend api application and by using req.cookies in the backend it will be shown. (you will need to install library like 'cookie-parser') There are many diffrent ways of implementation.

Comment: In my case the jwt is generated by a third server. So cookies are ok, but not for the first access.